# Formula works by dragging down the mouse but doesn't work with ArrayFormula

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have an issue that I just can't understand what is the problem. I am trying to compare two spreadsheets data to generate some results based on them.

What I have at the moment is a speadsheet to use as a query:

```
Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3
(dropdown) | (dropdown) | (dropdown)
(dropdown) | (dropdown) | (dropdown)
(dropdown) | (dropdown) | (dropdown)
(dropdown) | (dropdown) | (dropdown)
```

PS: Those four dropdowns on each column have the same value - the idea is to create a "multi-selection" dropdown for each question.

Then I have another spreadsheet (which is my "database") like this:

```
Is valid? -=- | Data I Need | Answer 1 | Answer 2 | Answer 3
TRUE / FALSE  | Data needed | Multiple answers separated by a comma
```

And I have a third spreadsheet called Results that should show only the matching questions/answers.

Everything works perfectly except for that fact that I have to drag down the formula through all my column to repeat the formula on my database spreadsheet. If I try to add an ArrayFunction on the first line it doesn't repeat the formula.

On my database spreadsheet I am using this formula in my "Is valid?" column (this is what I repeat my entire the column by draging down the mouse):

```
=IF(AND(SUM(
IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH("All",NamedRangeQuestion1)),SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(Database!C2,","))),NamedRangeQuestion1,0))))),TRUE,FALSE),
IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH("All",NamedRangeQuestion2)),SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(Database!D3,","))),NamedRangeQuestion3,0))))),TRUE,FALSE), IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH("All",NamedRangeQuestion2)),SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(Database!E3,","))),NamedRangeQuestion3,0))))),TRUE,FALSE)
) = COUNTIF(queryRowTotal,"Filtering"),COUNTIF(queryRowTotal,"Filtering") > 0),
TRUE,FALSE
)
```

It working perfect but the problem is that I have to drag down my formula to my entire column. If I try to use ArrayFormula on this it just doesn't work.

And on my "Results" spreadsheet I have:

```
=IFERROR(query(tableDatabase,"select B WHERE A = TRUE",-1),"")
```

What I need is to collect the matching results on my Results spreadsheet. It's all working fine but having to drag down the mouse instead of repeating the formula automatically is a deal break in my case.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12XRtLls8xYnebgdxERm2yOC2VIO3fmIG9bXd5zsm0Ec/copy) I have a working example of my spreadsheets.

What am I doing wrong here?

A better solution would be by creating a query direct on the results spreadsheet without having to write that code on the "database" spreadsheet, but I couldn't think in a solution using filter and/or query function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B), IF(
 REGEXMATCH(C2:C, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Query!A3:A6))*
 REGEXMATCH(D2:D, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Query!B3:B6))*
 REGEXMATCH(E2:E, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Query!C3:C6))=1, TRUE), ))
```

[image]

Comment: That's so elegant! Thanks for that! :)
Now I'm just wondering how to consider "All" as TRUE for any answer as it was in my original code.

Please consider [this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fw9RzLRkDJBQWZ7n-JIPFcnSmhTYxh_He7vzH6dpcCE/edit?usp=sharing) with your solution.